# Testing Electron application with org.openqa.selenium in a Java environment (Intellij)

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, electron, cucumber-jvm

Is there a way to create automated scenarios using `cucumber` and `selenium-webdriver` in Java environment for an Electron application?

I found some `Node.js` solutions on [electron.atom.io](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.7/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver/), but I would prefer Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Electron browser with [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/). Try creating WebDriver with similar setup:

```
// If chromediver executable is not in your project directory, 
//  point to it with this system variable
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe"); 

Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromeOptions.put("binary", "path/to/electron/binary");
chromeOptions.put("args", Arrays.asList(" path-to-electron-app"));
//eg.: chromeOptions.put("binary", "D:\\electron-quick-start\\node_modules\\electron-prebuilt\\dist\\electron.exe");
//     chromeOptions.put("args", Arrays.asList(" D:\\electron-quick-start"));
//  for some reason the app arg needs to follow a space on my Windows machine
    
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("chromeOptions", chromeOptions);
capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Here, the `path-to-electron-app` is the directory where the application source (`main.js`) is stored, and the electron binary is taken from dependencies downloaded during the build process.

Alternatively, if you want to work with precompiled application - it itself becomes the electron binary, and you can use the following:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe"); 
Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<>();
chromeOptions.put("binary", "D:\\my-electron-app.exe");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("chromeOptions", chromeOptions);
capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Very straightforward answer, helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: What the difference is between the path/to/electron/binary and the path-to-electron-app? Could you please give an example? Do they both end in exe or are we looking for a dll? i can get my chromedriver to open chrome but i can't get it to open the app

Comment: @LorenRogers if you work with exes, and not app sources, your exe **is** the electron/binary, so you can skip the args option. See the updated answer.

Comment: When using the compiled app and directing the binary to my .exe i get an error saying  no chrome binary at Users/myUsername/electronAppFolder/dist_electron/win-unpacked/myApp.exe.  I even have the System.Setproperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"," C://chromdriver.exe") set.  I get the chrome browser opened and then the test failes with the message no chrome binary at Users/myUsername/electronAppFolder/dist_electron/win-unpacked/myApp.exe  what am I missing?